# How to calculate duration in hours in Teradata

Tags: sql, syntax, teradata

I'm working on a requirement where i have to calculate the duration between two date derived date time columns. The result should be in hours.

```
(DateField1 + TimeField1) - (DateField2 + TimeField2)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your required output (DateField1 + TimeField1) - (DateField2 + TimeField2)

Which is equivalent to (DateField1 - DateField2) + (TimeField1 - TimeField2)

If you want timestamp difference only in hours (ignoring minutes & Seconds)

`select  ((DateField1 - DateField2) HOUR(4))+( (TimeField1 - TimeField2) HOUR(4)) required_output
from dateTable;`

And if you want timestamp difference considering hours,minutes & Seconds

`SELECT
   (DateField1 - DateField2) HOUR(4) to SECOND(4) t1,
   (TimeField1 - TimeField2)  HOUR(4) to SECOND(4) t2,
   EXTRACT(HOUR from t1)+EXTRACT(MINUTE from t1)/60.0 +EXTRACT(SECOND from t1)/(60.0*60.0) t1_HOUR,
   EXTRACT(HOUR from t2)+EXTRACT(MINUTE from t2)/60.0 +EXTRACT(SECOND from t2)/(60.0*60.0) t2_HOUR,
   t1_HOUR+t2_HOUR required_output
FROM dateTable;`

Note: Above logic can handle time difference for maximum of 9999 hour between 2 timestamp, if you want to handle bigger value then you may consider adding Day(4) to Second(4) and update logic accordingly

Table & data if you want to play

`CREATE volatile table dateTable( DateField1  TIMESTAMP(0),DateField2  TIMESTAMP(0),TimeField1 TIMESTAMP(0),TimeField2 TIMESTAMP(0))on commit preserve rows;
INSERT INTO dateTable VALUES (current_date,current_date-1,current_date-2,current_date-3)`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Learnt something new from this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate by `TIMESTAMP` and use [HOUR(4)](http://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/0.167-t/functions/datetime.html#hour) to get `hour`

```
SELECT cast((DateField1 + TimeField1)as TIMESTAMP) - cast((DateField2 + TimeField2)as TIMESTAMP) HOUR(4)
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Comment: @MeetRohan You can mark this answer or upvote if that help you :)